# HTTP to HTTPS wordpress media upload issue

Tags: wordpress, image, http, https, media

I have a website https://mycpadashboard.com/. I have installed SSL to it but whenever I upload media it first creates an image URL with HTTP, not with HTTPS. Though when I clicked on HTTP generated image URL it is redirecting which is a good thing. But I am performing a technical audit and they are showing me warnings that some of the URLs(same non HTTP images) are having HTTP links. I have checked all the settings.
Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: Have you changed the url in the wordpress settings to https? you find it under Settings - General in the admin backend.

Comment: It was HTTP at first, now I have changed it to HTTPS, Thanks for solving my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Go to wp-options from database php my admin and change the link from http to https. so your all images will convert to https.
I just saw an image of playstore in footer with http URL.
[image]

Comment: I have changed it to HTTPS, now when I upload a media HTTPS URL is generating, Thanks for the quick help. Much appreciated